# Normal matrix and inner product

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show that a $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is normal if and only if $$<A\vec{v},A\vec{w}>=<A^*\vec{v},A^*\vec{w}>.$$

So I tried
\begin{align*}
&(A\vec{v},A\vec{v})+(A\vec{v},A\vec{w})+(A\vec{w},A\vec{v})+(A\vec{w},A\vec{w})\\
&=(A\vec{v}+A\vec{w},A\vec{v}+A\vec{w})\\
&=(A^*\vec{v}+A^*\vec{w},A^*\vec{v}+A^*\vec{w})\\
&=(A^*\vec{v},A^*\vec{v})+(A^*\vec{v},A^*\vec{w})+(A^*\vec{w},A^*\vec{v})+(A^*\vec{w},A^*\vec{w})
\end{align*}
and all that left is
$$(A\vec{v},A\vec{w})+(A\vec{w},A\vec{v})=(A^*\vec{v},A^*\vec{w})+(A^*\vec{w},A^*\vec{v})$$
I think that the conclusion can be drown from the fact $$(A\vec{w},A\vec{v})=\overline{(A\vec{v},A\vec{w})}.$$

But I just can't proceed. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Suppse that $A$ is normal. Then

$<Av,Aw>=<A^*Av,w>=<AA^*v,w>=<A^*v,A^*w>.$

2. Now suppose that $<Av,Aw>=<A^*v,A^*w>$ holds for all $v,w$. Then we get

$<A^*Av,w>=<AA^*v,w>$, thus $<(A^*A-AA^*)v,w>=0$.

Then take $w:=A^*A-AA^*)v$ to derive that

$||(A^*A-AA^*)v||=0$